# Insert a new ViewController in the appDelegate?

Tags: ios

I created a project and completed the main functionality, now I want to add an intro view before my actual/Main viewcontroller. I tried to replace all the instances of the old/Main viewcontroller with the intro view that I just created so that the appdelegate opens up the intro view by default and then I can navigate through the remaining views.

But it still opens the main view rather than the new intro view. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the references in MainWindow.xib?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I havnt done that. I am new to this can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Look in the properties of the objects in Interface Builder.  The main view controller will need to have its class changed to your new class.   This is done in panel on the right. also, make sure that it is calling the correct nib